# how to change Grails GORM id column name and use sequence

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In a Grails/GORM app, can I rename the implicit domain id column to entity_id and auto-increment using an existing sequence?

```
 class Practitioner {

   Long entityId
   String providerName

   static mapping = {
     id name: 'entityId', column: 'entity_id', generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'hibernate_sequence']
   }
}
```

Attempting to save in console fails, (and yes, sequence exists in my local Postgres database)

```
Practitioner p = new Practitioner(providerName: 'p')
p.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
```

Error

```
grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 
'com.transcendinsights.dp.measureresult.snapshot.Practitioner' on field 'entityId': rejected value [null]; codes
```

Super thanks for helping!

Comment: Try dropping your `Practitioner` table and regenerate it.

Comment: Thank you Parth but I am already re-creating each time I run liquidbase locally.  For now I decided to remove the "entityId" property, and only keep the column mapping i.e. column: 'entity_id'.   The sequence now works, but it's less than ideal.